# Follow vs Follow after

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

Is the expression "follow after", e.g; "He followed after her", grammatically incorrect or an awkward phrasing?
I use the phrase "follow after" to put an emphasis on the action, it also gives me a subtle impression of dependence, as if, the subject is following the other person either very closely or is "following at the heels" of that person, and if they had lingered in the previous room, for instance, they'd run to catch that person.

I have googled my issue, and found one site (wordreference.com) with a thread on this and with various answers. I'm also guessing that the answer technically lies in the definition of "follow". However, I kept seeing this phrase used several times in different books, and I have been using it myself.

I have seen that it might be:

- Sloppy English. Yet numerous works seem to use it? I wouldn't have picked up on it, otherwise.
- Might indicate tagging along
- Might imply following someone without their knowledge.

As you can see, I've interpreted this phrase completely differently. I have also seen that "follow" is a statement of sequence in space or time and follow after is a statement of volition, of active pursuit (which contradicts with the statement that it implies following someone without their knowledge).

Could you guys offer some clarifications and a final say on what follow/follow after actually mean/imply?

Comment: You need to include several of the actual sentences from the books you mention. 'Follow' has more than one sense.

Comment: Most of the early examples of 'followed after' I've found in a quick search are from the AV, and are just (in my opinion an archaic) synonym for 'followed'. Certain prepositions are sometimes optional with certain verbs: She brushed [against] the fence. They appealed [against] the decision. / The 'succeeded' sense of course complicates.

Comment: "followed after" usually means "came later, in a similar role".

Answer (score 1):

> He  followed her.
>
> He  followed  after  her.

I  think  they  have  two  meanings — one  literal  and  the  other  metaphorical.

He  followed  her  means  he  was  behind  her  in  walking  or  in life.

He  followed  after  her  means  he followed  her  in walking literally  and idiomatically it  means took  over  charge  from her, succeeded, superseded,  or  replaced her  in  a  position .

Follow  after  is found  in  the  King  James version of  the  Bible.

Here  is  a  Link

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-follow-after.354651/

Here  is  a  link  which  helps  you know  the  difference.

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/follow%20after

Comment: No. "He followed after her" does not say either that he overtook her or that he overcame her. Either you are misunderstanding the phrase, or you are misunderstanding the words "overtake" and "overcome".

Comment: That is a different sense of 'follow after', meaning something like 'to be the next one in a list'.

Comment: @  colin Fine.You  are right.I  have edited  my  answer.Thank  you.

Comment: Follow after sounds a little strange.  But, suppose, A, B and C followed X, in the same order, one can say, B followed after A; or C followed after B.